# How to find and store specific lines from a file in c#

Tags: c#

I want to search some lines containing some specific data and store these data in a list, how can I do this? I have written this code for my project, but this code can only find and store the first line containing my wanted data because all these lines are started with the same structure, for an example, my data is repeated in lines 100, 250, 400, 660, and all these lines are stated with "|PROD    |OIL     |" .

```
double[] oil_prdc   = new double[10];
double[] water_prdc = new double[10];                  
double[] gas_prdc   = new double[10];
double[] water_injc = new double[10];
double[] gas_injc   = new double[10];  
int length_time = 5;
string[][] characters = new string[2391][];
string [] Charss;
string[][]counter = new string[20][];
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{                    
    for (int i = 0; i < length_time; i++)
    {
        total_production.Add(null);
        total_production[i] = new List<_5_points>(); 
        while (line.Contains("|PROD    |OIL     |"))
        {
            Charss = line.Split('|');

            for (int j = 0; j < Charss.Length; j++)
            {
                if (j == 9)
                {
                    oil_prdc[i] = 1000 * Convert.ToDouble(Charss[j]);                                        
                }
                else if (j == 10)
                {
                    water_prdc[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Charss[j]);
                }
                else if (j == 11)
                {
                    gas_prdc[i] = 1000 * Convert.ToDouble(Charss[j]);
                }
            }
            count++;
            if (count > Charss.Length) break;

        }

        while (line.Contains(" |WINJ    |WAT     "))
        {
            Charss = line.Split('|');
            for (int jj = 0; jj < Charss.Length; jj++)
            {
                if (jj == 8)
                {
                    water_injc[i] = 1000 * Convert.ToDouble(Charss[jj]);
                }
            }
            count++;
            if (count > Charss.Length) break;
        }
        while (line.Contains(" |GINJ    |Passive "))
        {
            Charss = line.Split('|');
            for (int ij = 0; ij < Charss.Length; ij++)
            {
                if (ij == 9)
                {
                    gas_injc[i] = 1000 * Convert.ToDouble(Charss[ij]);
                }
            }
            count++;
            if (count > Charss.Length) break;
        }
        _5_points temp=new _5_points{OIL_PRD =oil_prdc[i],GAS_PRD=gas_prdc[i],WATER_PRD=water_prdc[i],WATER_INJ=water_injc[i],GAS_INJ=gas_injc[i]};
        total_production[i].Add(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the input file in format text or other format as xml?

Comment: Parsing text files is not simple.  Being doing it for 40 years and I'm pretty good .  Without seeing the actual text file I cannot give recommendations.  I've seen too many issues to give an answer.  Using While loops like you are doing usually doesn't work very well.  I usually use a state machine which is very robust and eliminates a lot of spaghetti code.

Comment: If you want I can show my text file, I cannot paste this because of lack characters.

Answer (score 0):

Example of how to read a file:

```
try 
{
    // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
    // The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt")) 
    {
        string line;
        // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
        // the file is reached.
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    // Let the user know what went wrong.
    Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Search for specific text in each "line":

```
public static string getBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd)
{
    int Start, End;
    if (strSource.Contains(strStart) && strSource.Contains(strEnd))
    {
        Start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, 0) + strStart.Length;
        End = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);
        return strSource.Substring(Start, End - Start);
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
string text = "This is an example string and my data is here";
string data = getBetween(text, "my", "is");
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, Dear Tobbe×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes